# Why does Allah care what I do?

Tags: allah, sin

Why does Allah care about anything I do? Especially things that don't affect other people? For example if I am a hermit, never see another person, and do nothing but sin, why is this bad? Why does Allah care?

Furthermore, say it does affect other people. Say I am a mass murderer, why would Allah care about this?

Comment: Briefly: He fetched us here to be tested to live in normal and good way, not... / Otherwise He wouldn't creature us... Good luck dear mate

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah the most Gracious the most Merciful,

I will first present a story to you,
I am a manager in a factory and have applied certain rules and obligations towards it, such rules are applied to whoever is working in the factory. I am in need of a single labour/worker for checking the semi-finished product. I appoint you for such wage and for a certain time period.

Now what you do is instead of deficating yourself to work, you are going around and doing as you please or taking the waste, dublicate and extra material without permission, drinking while workig etc. but mostly you are doing is not interacting with your co workers about work concerns and going against the rules i have applied to all.

The rules in the factory telates to the legal and illegal things Allah has obligated on man kind, the work is worshipping him only in obedience and faith, so this should explain to you that he is the owner of your soul and he can take it away. You have come to this world for a certain objective and that is to collect good deeds and worship Allah only for Akhirah.

And in hope that you will in shaa Allah leave all the bad you do or sin, Allah do not like he transgressors but loves to forgive who ask for forgiveness. :)

Answer (score 1):

Allah (swt) is pure of any wants. He made humans and jinns for his worship. Worship is to live according to His guidance. All His guidance is that which is good for us. All that is bad for us is sin.In this temporary life all are in great loss except those who believe and do good deeds.And those who practice patience and recommend it. And those who live by truth and recommend it.
 Those who believe get tested and raised in levels as they pass the tests. Shaitan /Devil is the open enemy of Mankind and he tries all sorts of tricks to deceive humans and makes them go astray. So every time a person sins he ought to ask for forgiveness. For Allah is often forgiving. There is a lot of His mercy which makes humans get back on track. 
When a person follows His instructions he gets purity of thought and peace of mind. He is saved from various diseases of the heart like jealousy, lust, greed. 
  So to come back to your answer. Allah has guided us to save ourselves from the deceptions of this world which is less then a drop of water compared to an ocean that is hereafter. It is His great gift to Mankind to show them the way to eternal bliss if their any to take heed.
  You are free to make your choices but you are not free of the consequences! 
So He cares if you care.

Answer (score 1):

God is kind and merciful...

Humans either go to heaven or hell...since this world is a just world...

He doesn't need his servants, nor their prayers, yet he doesn't like his servants to hell.

He gives instructions on how to achieve heaven... if it's important for you then you follow...

Conclusion: He doesn't need your prayers...but he would happy to see you go to the heavens...as he is the beneficent and merciful i.e. he does care that much!